# Извлечение js кода из onclick`а в span`е

Tags: javascript

На сайте есть список ссылок, код выглядит следующим образом:

```
...
<div id="start-ads-575368">
   <span onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; funcjs['start_youtube'](575368, 'b547e1897655c8ed23240e6396e0c838', 'ads-start', 'ads');" title="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbJGcCEd9Qg" style="cursor:pointer;color:#006699;">Посмотреть видео</span><br>
   <span class="serf-text">Просмотр видеоролика</span>
</div>
...
<div id="start-ads-577639">
   <span onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; funcjs['start_youtube'](577639, '464bc1202c4d593fe9675385595da247', 'ads-start', 'ads');" title="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1aXXArDCfq4" style="cursor:pointer;color:#006699;">Посмотреть видео</span><br>
   <span class="serf-text">Просмотр видеоролика</span>
</div>
...
```

Вопрос двойной, один из вариантов подойдёт:

1. Как обратиться по шаблону **"start-ads-"**, чтобы потом произвести `click()`;
2. Как вытащить содержимое `onclick`, чтобы выполнить функцию `funcjs['start_youtube']` имеющуюся на сайте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
//обратиться по шаблону (^ - начинается с ...)
let divs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='start-ads']");
let div_ids = [...divs].map(item => item.id)
console.log(div_ids);

//функции
let spans = document.querySelectorAll('div span:first-child');
let fc = [...spans].map(item => item.getAttribute('onclick').split(';')[1].trim())
console.log(fc)
```

```html
<div id="start-ads-575368">
   <span onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; funcjs['start_youtube'](575368, 'b547e1897655c8ed23240e6396e0c838', 'ads-start', 'ads');" title="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbJGcCEd9Qg" style="cursor:pointer;color:#006699;">Посмотреть видео</span><br>
   <span class="serf-text">Просмотр видеоролика</span>
</div>

<div id="start-ads-577639">
   <span onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; funcjs['start_youtube'](577639, '464bc1202c4d593fe9675385595da247', 'ads-start', 'ads');" title="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1aXXArDCfq4" style="cursor:pointer;color:#006699;">Посмотреть видео</span><br>
   <span class="serf-text">Просмотр видеоролика</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое. Каким бы не вводил запрос в поисковик про шаблон, то ничего не находил

Comment: @MaxDown Пожалуйста. Здесь подробнее
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714090/queryselector-wildcard-element-match